# Search filter doesn't work correctly after adding new data with Laravel Scout on Meilisearch

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I have Classified model

```
public function searchableAs()
{
    return 'classifieds_index';
}

public function toSearchableArray()
{
    return [
        'title' => $this->title,
        'description' => strip_tags($this->content),
        'category_id' => (int) $this->category_id,
        'category-title' => $this->category->name,
        'status' => (int) $this->status,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
    ];
}
```

and want to be able to search it and filter by status. I have set index settings like this

```
    'index-settings' => [
         'classifieds_index' => [
             'filterableAttributes'=> ['id', 'status', 'category_id'],
             'displayedAttributes' => ['id', 'title'],
         ]
    ],
],
```

After creating/saving Classified model I'm able to find it, but not with filter on. Only after flushing and importing data with Scout.

```
    $index = $client->index('classifieds_index')
        ->search('kei', [
            'filter' => 'status = 1',
        ]);
```

If I set filter status = 0 then meilisearch finds it without flushing.